# how to open text file when you click it in listview

Tags: android

I can't open text files when I click on it my programm go to the start page. I see many codes 
where you shulod know the exact location of text files but how can I open text files when I don't know its exact location.

Main activity open xml which contain 3 buttons when I press Browse button app open all files in phone

```
package com.example.fileexplorerb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private static final int REQUEST_PATH = 1;

    Button browseButton;
    Button exitButton;
    Button nextButton;

    String curFileName;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        browseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        browseButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        nextButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        // See which child activity is calling us back.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PATH){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
                curFileName = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName"); 
                //edittext.setText(curFileName);
            }
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, FileChooser.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent1,REQUEST_PATH);
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2){
            finish();
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button3){
            //Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, FileChooser.class);
            //startActivityForResult(intent2,REQUEST_PATH);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setType("application/txt");

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


}
```

File ArrayAdapter shows file size, date when it was created and name

```
package com.example.fileexplorerb;

import java.util.List; 

import android.content.Context; 
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

    private Context c;
    private int id;
    private List<Item>items;

    public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        c = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = objects;
    }
    public Item getItem(int i)
     {
         return items.get(i);
     }
     @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               View v = convertView;
               if (v == null) {
                   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   v = vi.inflate(id, null);
               }

               /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
            //convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

               final Item o = items.get(position);
               if (o != null) {
                       TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                       TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                       TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                       /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
                        ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
                        int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                        Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                        imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

                       if(t1!=null)
                        t1.setText(o.getName());
                       if(t2!=null)
                            t2.setText(o.getData());
                       if(t3!=null)
                            t3.setText(o.getDate());

               }
               return v;
       }

}
```

FileChooser set the images to files and

```
package com.example.fileexplorerb;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.DateFormat; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView; 

public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {

    private File currentDir;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        currentDir = new File("/sdcard/");
        fill(currentDir); 
    }
    private void fill(File f)
    {
        File[]dirs = f.listFiles(); 
         this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
         List<Item>dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
         List<Item>fls = new ArrayList<Item>();
         try{
             for(File ff: dirs)
             { 
                Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified()); 
                DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()){


                    File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles(); 
                    int buf = 0;
                    if(fbuf != null){ 
                        buf = fbuf.length;
                    } 
                    else buf = 0; 
                    String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                    if(buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                    else num_item = num_item + " items";

                    //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(),num_item,date_modify,ff.getAbsolutePath(),"directory_icon")); 
                }
                else
                {

                    fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(),ff.length() + " Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(),"file_icon"));
                }
             }
         }catch(Exception e){    

         }
         Collections.sort(dir);
         Collections.sort(fls);
         dir.addAll(fls);
         if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
             dir.add(0,new Item("..","Parent Directory","",f.getParent(),"directory_up"));
         adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this,R.layout.file_view,dir);
         this.setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Item o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon")||o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up")){
                currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
                fill(currentDir);
        }
        else
        {
            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }
    private void onFileClick(Item o)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Clicked: "+ currentDir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("GetPath",currentDir.toString());
        intent.putExtra("GetFileName",o.getName());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }



}



XML for main activity shows main menu when you open application 


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="142dp"
        android:text="Browse" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:text="Exit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

file_view XML  shows all file in phone

```
file view 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FileChooser` activity should also return the complete path to the file. It must know it as you are using the directory in `private void fill(File f)` - memorize the `f` somewhere and use it later to combine the directory path and the file name itself.